Shapeable image view bottom corner radius not displaying correct radius
I have a material card view with corner radius of 28dp. I want to display a shapeable image with the same corner radius for all corners. Image 1
In this image, i have the material card view with 28dp rounded corners and shapeable image view with rounded corner of 28dp. Looks fine but if i add a text view below it the bottom corners of the shapeable image view look weird.
Image 2
Based on this image, the bottom corners dont look like they are 28dp, for the shapeable image view, im using a style for rounded corner 28dp
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".com.example.TestActivity">
    
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
        app:strokeWidth="3dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView

                android:id="@+id/shapeableImageView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:10"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/HomeCardShape"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/card_test_image" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shapeableImageView2" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

this is the entire layout
<style name="HomeCardShape">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">28dp</item> 
    </style


If I understand you correctly, it's an optical illusion because the ShapeableImageView's edges are covered by the CardView stroke, so the corner curves don't look complete. If you put that in an image editor and just slide the CardView down, you'll see that they're the same radius: https://i.sstatic.net/pBZDqoif.png. You could inset the ShapeableImageView by the stroke width, and subtract the same from its corner radius, then it would look right: https://i.sstatic.net/v48bRro7.png. However, you might have problems with tiny gaps in the top corners, and you may have to fiddle with it.

Oh, just realized, you can leave the top corners at their original radius, and only set the bottom two to 25dp. That, and a android:layout_margin="3dp" on the <ShapeableImageView> should give you the same results as the top image in my second link there.

Oops, wait, I got my reasoning backwards. The top corners would need a lesser radius to close the gap, so something like 24dp.

You can modify bottom corners with style settings:
<style name="HomeCardShape">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <!--item name="cornerSize">28dp</item--> 
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">28dp</item> 
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">28dp</item> 
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item> 
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item> 
</style

Setting bottom corners to 0dp will make them look better.
